# flutter app , Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, null, operator-keyword, dart-null-safety

This is a simple flutter app. I am getting this error on my signup page which connects to firebase.
when i try to sign up, it remains on thinking with ⭕ spinning, i am getting this error in the debug console:

```
VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      _SignupScreenState.signUpUser package:instagram_flutter/screens/signup_screen.dart:5
```

any thoughts?

here is the code that I believe is the source of the problem at:

```
 (_image != null
                  ? CircleAvatar
```

This is that block of code:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              _image != null
                  ? CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 32,
                      backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    )
                  : const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 32,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          'https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png'),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
```

I am new to coding and flutter, what should I put to replace the "?"

here is the entire code for the sign_up_screen (it is taken from a tutorial):

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/resources/auth_methods.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/utils/utils.dart';

import '../responsive/responsive_layout_screen.dart';
import '../widgets/text_field_input.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bioController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  Uint8List? _image;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _usernameController.dispose();
  }

  void signUpUser() async {
    // set loading to true
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    // signup user using our authmethodds
    String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
        username: _usernameController.text,
        bio: _bioController.text,
        file: _image!);
    // if string returned is sucess, user has been created
    if (res == "success") {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      // navigate to the home screen
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const ResponsiveLayout(
            mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
            webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      // show the error
      showSnackBar(context, res);
    }
  }

  selectImage() async {
    Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    // set state because we need to display the image we selected on the circle avatar
    setState(() {
      _image = im;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Container(),
                flex: 2,
              ),
              SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/ic_instagram.svg',
                color: primaryColor,
                height: 64,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 64,
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  _image != null
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 64,
                          backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        )
                      : const CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 64,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: -10,
                    left: 80,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: selectImage,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                hintText: 'Enter your username',
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                textEditingController: _usernameController,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                hintText: 'Enter your email',
                textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textEditingController: _emailController,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                hintText: 'Enter your password',
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                textEditingController: _passwordController,
                isPass: true,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                hintText: 'Enter your bio',
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                textEditingController: _bioController,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  child: !_isLoading
                      ? const Text(
                          'Sign up',
                        )
                      : const CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: primaryColor,
                        ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                  decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    ),
                    color: blueColor,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: signUpUser,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(),
                flex: 2,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: const Text(
                      'Already have an account?',
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      child: const Text(
                        ' Login.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

there is also the auth page, which includes a warning regarding

```
file != null) {:
```

the warning says:

```
The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.
Remove the condition.dartunnecessary_null_comparison
```

auth_methods.dart:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/resources/storage_methods.dart';

class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //sign up user
  Future<String> signUpUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String username,
    required String bio,
    required Uint8List file,
  }) async {
    String res = "Some error Occurred";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty ||
          password.isNotEmpty ||
          username.isNotEmpty ||
          bio.isNotEmpty ||
          file != null) {
        // registering user in auth with email and password
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );

        String photoUrl = await StorageMethods()
            .uploadImageToStorage('profilePics', file, false);

        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(cred.user!.uid).set({
          'username': username,
          'uid': cred.user!.uid,
          'email': email,
          'bio': bio,
          'followers': [],
          'following': [],
          'photoUrl': photoUrl,
        });

        res = "success";
      } else {
        res = "Please enter all the fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

// logging in user
  Future<String> loginUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    String res = "Some error Occurred";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty || password.isNotEmpty) {
        // logging in user with email and password
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        res = "success";
      } else {
        res = "Please enter all the fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the declaration for _image is of type MemoryImage like this: `MemoryImage? _image;` Then, when using the value for the background image, just use `_image`, not `MemoryImage(_image!)`.

Comment: When you the declaration, do u mean when i say: Uint8List? _image; ? If I change it to: MemoryImage? _image;  and put _image instead of MemoryImage(_image!), i get the error: "The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'." Because later I am saying: file: _image!; I'll post the entire cose thnx

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your grammar, but if I do, that is correct.

Comment: yes i meant to say, "When you say declaration, do u mean when i'm declaring variables under class, currently i say,  Uint8List? _image; If I change it to: MemoryImage? _image; and put _image instead of MemoryImage(_image!), i get the error: "The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'." Because later I am saying: file: _image!; I'll post the entire code thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way..

```
Stack(
            children: [
              _image == null
                  ? const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 32,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          'https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png'),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ):
              CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 32,
                      backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
```

Comment: If I do it that way I get the following errors: Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception. A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Uint8List' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'. Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

On your `signUpUser` you are directly using bang`!` without checking null.

Here

```dart
  // signup user using our authmethodds
        ...
        file: _image!);
```

Try

```dart
  void signUpUser() async {
    if (_image == null) {
      debugPrint("got null on _image");
      _isLoading = false;
      return;
    }
```

And everything seems ok on `Stack`